# Expressão Regular varia de acordo com a linguagem?

Tags: regex, expressões

Maioria das linguagens tem suporte para *Regex* (Expressões Regulares) mas, por exemplo, o JavaScript não tem *Negative Lookhead* (`(?<`) , entretanto já o .NET Framework tem praticamente todas funções do Regex. Minha dúvida é:

> A Sintaxe, função e ortografia do Regex varia junto a linguagem em que está sendo refenciado?

Comment: Há variações sim. Dá uma olhada [aqui na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#Language_features)

Comment: O regularexpressions.info tem [várias tabelas](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) comparando os recursos presentes em diversas linguagens e plataformas (eu me lembro de ter uma tabelona com tudo junto, mas nunca a encontro quando procuro...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NÃO**

Não varia, o que ocorre é que ela está em sempre em desenvolvimento, e existe um *gap* entre a publicação de um novo recursos e as bibliotecas de diversas linguagens passarem a suporta-las.

Entretanto, uma expressão possui a mesmo funcionalidade em qualquer que seja a linguagem. O que pode ocorrer é, se for uma expressão/recurso novo, essa linguagem pode ainda não suportar.

Mas, variar, não varia.

Comment: Quem negativo, por gentileza, se manifeste.